# Clear div when print window closes

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to have it so that when the print windows closes that a div is cleared to have nothing in it. This is my code now

```
printReportAssets = function(){
    var ReportAssets = document.getElementById("ReportAssets").innerHTML;
    $('.target').append(ReportAssets)
    window.print();
};
```

I want to somehow add something like

`.innnerHTML = ''`

I am not sure how to trigger this nor reset the HTML to blank.

Comment: Can you clarify what/where exactly is the print window in your application?

Comment: Just use CSS Media Print

Comment: @epascarello I do have CSS media print. That works for making the print show what I want but after a user closes the window I can't seem to find a way with CSS

Here is my CSS

`@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #section-to-print, #section-to-print * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #section-to-print {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.onafterprint = function(){$('.target').html("")};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onafterprint = function(){
   div.innerHTML = '';
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Answers with only code in them tend to get flagged for deletion as they are "low quality".  Please read the help section on answering questions then consider adding some commentary to your Answer.